# Scipy.signal method 'filtfilt()' doesn't recognized correctly

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

It's my first time working with scipy.signal library and I am experimenting an error with the method `filtfilt()`.

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
Fs = 1000
# s is an array of numbers
a=signal.firwin(10, cutoff=0.5/(Fs/2))

ss = s - np.mean(s)
se = signal.filtfilt(a, 1, ss, method="gust")
```

When I execute this code I get the next error:

```
TypeError: filtfilt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

But in the documentation of the method it is clearly shown that the parameter 'method' exists.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Why not accepting the answer?? Didn't it resolve your issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess you have different versions of scipy in use. The documentation of [filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) says the 'gust' method was added in 0.16. I assume the method parameter does not exist in earlier versions.

Comment: Indeed: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html